# Site summary when posting links

Tags: javascript, php

Does anyone how to do the following: when user inputs a link, how to get that page summary, so when you input `facebook.com` you get a page summary like title. I've tried googling it, but nothing came up.

Comment: You are gonna have to clarify your question, all I understod was that you tried to google something.

Comment: copy a link to facebook chatbox,and you will see,what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding meta tags to your site so when facebook parses the link it will search for the correct meta information. Not only facebook will parse the link either.

```
<meta property=”og:title” content=”Your Page Summary goes here,” />
```

https://blog.kissmetrics.com/open-graph-meta-tags/

If you are looking to add it to your website read this article.
http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/06/extract-url-content-like-facebook-with-php-and-jquery

Answer (score 1):

As I understood your question (but if you clarify it, it'll be better ;))

You have to use `Javascript` on client or `cUrl` on server side to query the website and get the content.
Then parse the received contents to extract data you want to display.

Comment: yes,like facebook does when you post a link in chat box

Comment: Yeah so my answer fit. You just have to construct the html to display the data you got in php.